# Is there any docker containers for ROS?

Tags: docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any docker containers for ROS? I googled but didn't find anything.
If there is no containers what is the best way to start building one and share with you guys?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98301/is-there-any-docker-containers-for-ros?/) by [Oleg](https://answers.ros.org/users/8506/oleg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [linas](https://answers.ros.org/users/26009/linas/) on 2016-02-20**:
Its not that hard to set up ROS in a docker container. The problem is that it doesn't work very well, due to networking issues: ROS and Docker clash over how they want to do networking. A long, detailed analysis is here: https://github.com/opencog/docker/tree/master/indigo  (about half-way down).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've made a basic Dockerfile which installs ROS hydro on top of the ubuntu precise image:

https://gist.github.com/jonbinney/7365141

You can remove the vnc stuff if you don't want to be able to see GUI apps. I'm still working out how to handle networking, for instance exposing the right ports for ROS publishers.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2013-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2016-07-29**:
So... have you been successful figuring out how to expose the dynamic node ports?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've made the container with vnc and web view for vnc.
It installs ros indigo base on top of ubuntu 14.04 trusty, mount and configures workspace, launches vnc server.
If someone wants ros desktop full, just fix the line in the Dockerfile.

https://github.com/osblinnikov/rosDocker

---

Originally posted by [Oleg](https://answers.ros.org/users/8506/oleg/) with karma: 11 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an old question, but for those who may stumble across this, there are now official ROS [1] and Gazebo [2] Docker images available on Docker Hub.

You can pull the latest LTS version of ROS via:
`docker pull ros`
as well as the latest release of Gazebo similarly:
`docker pull gazebo`

Please check the full description provided on the respective Docker Hub repo pages for further details.
1 [hub.docker.com/_/ros](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros/)
2 [hub.docker.com/_/gazebo](https://hub.docker.com/_/gazebo/)

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2015-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6